# Envio mensaje por php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hola buenas no se porque no recibo el email mediante php, he puesto preventDefault ya que no quiero que se envie de forma normal sino por ajax, recibo la respuesta mediante la alerta PERO on recibo el mensaje en mi email. el status code esta bien pero no receaving. Alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    let nombre = $('#campoNombre').val();
    let email = $('#campoEmail').val();
    let telefono = $('#campoTelefono').val();
    let mensaje = $('#campoMensaje').val();

    if (nombre.length <= 2) {
      alertaError('El nombre es demasiado corto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (email.includes('@') == false || email.includes('.') == false || email.indexOf('@') < 1) {
      alertaError('El email no es correcto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (telefono.length < 9) {
      alertaError('El telefono debe tener al menos 9 numeros');
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    else if (mensaje.length <= 10) {
      alertaError('El mensaje es demasiado corto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post({

        url:'http://www.franciscomanrique.com/contact.php',

        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(datos) {
          let texto = datos.saludo + '<br>' + datos.mensaje;
          msg(texto, 2);
        }
      });

      //Empty field info except button
      $('input:not(.boton), textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
      });
    }

  });

});

//ERROR MSG
function alertaError(texto){
  $('#alerta p').text(texto);
  $('#alerta').addClass('visible');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#alerta').removeClass('visible');
  },3000);
}

// MSG

function msg(mensajes, tiempo) {

  $('#alerta p').html(mensajes);

  $('#alerta').addClass('visible');

  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#alerta').removeClass('visible');
  },tiempo * 2000);
}
```

```html
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $jsondata = array();

     $jsondata['saludo'] = '¡Hola '. $_POST['campoNombre'] . '!';

     $jsondata['mensaje'] = 'Nos pondremos en contacto contigo lo antes posible';


  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($jsondata);
  exit();



  if($_POST) {
      $to_Email       = "fmls1989@gmail.com"; // email de recepción
      $subject        = 'SOLICITUD DE CONTACTO'; // asunto

      // saneado de seguridad
      $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["campoNombre"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["campoEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["campoTelefono"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      // composición de email
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=charset=UTF-8";
      $headers .= 'From: SOLICITUD DE CONTACTO' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

      $body = "Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de contacto:"."\r\n";
      $body .= "Nombre: " . $user_Name ."\r\n";
      $body .= "Correo: " . $user_Email ."\r\n";
      $body .= "Mensaje: " . $user_Message ."\r\n";


      // envío de email
      $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $body, $headers);

  }


?>
```

Comment: Quita la @ de delante de mail para poder ver el error.

Comment: no me da error no sale nada, pone todo okay pero en receaving 0ms

Comment: Si hay error, estará en el log del apache, llamado normalmente error.log

Comment: Lo más seguro es que el mensaje se esté enviando correctamente, pero no lo recibes porque los encabezados no son suficientes para pasar filtros anti spam y te recomiendo usar PhpMailer.

Answer (score 1):

**Si lo estas probando en localhost es imposible que el correo salga**

Para que salga necesitas un servicio como sendmail o un cliente smtp con autenticacion como phpmailer.

Comment: no es localhost, esta publicada la pagina en www.franciscomanrique.com

Comment: Has realizado pruebas unitarias colo con mail desde el servidor?

Comment: soy nuevo en esto, a que te refieres? Como hago eso?

Comment: haz una prueba unitaria para descartar que la funcionalidad de la opción mail funcione correctamente en tu servidor, muchos servidores bloquean la salida de correos por un control de spam saliente